# Reading XML File as if Parent Elements Don't Exist

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading an XML file that lists forecast time steps for the weather. The forecasts are split up into days which contain a few time steps. I want to read the time steps all at one instead of going through each day at a time, how can I do this? This is the XML I am reading:

```
<Location i="3808" lat="50.218" lon="-5.33" name="CAMBORNE" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE" elevation="87.0">
  <Period type="Day" value="2014-08-16Z">
    <Rep D="WSW" F="11" G="18" H="91" Pp="0" S="4" T="11" V="VG" W="1" U="1">360</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="15" G="11" H="73" Pp="1" S="9" T="16" V="VG" W="3" U="1">540</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="14" G="18" H="66" Pp="3" S="13" T="17" V="VG" W="3" U="4">720</Rep>
    <Rep D="W" F="15" G="18" H="67" Pp="5" S="13" T="17" V="VG" W="7" U="5">900</Rep>
    <Rep D="W" F="13" G="20" H="75" Pp="34" S="13" T="16" V="VG" W="7" U="1">1080</Rep>
    <Rep D="WSW" F="12" G="18" H="83" Pp="7" S="9" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">1260</Rep>
  </Period>
  <Period type="Day" value="2014-08-17Z">
    <Rep D="W" F="12" G="20" H="83" Pp="38" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">0</Rep>
    <Rep D="W" F="12" G="18" H="85" Pp="8" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">180</Rep>
    <Rep D="W" F="12" G="20" H="86" Pp="53" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="12" U="1">360</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="22" H="79" Pp="30" S="16" T="16" V="VG" W="7" U="1">540</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="25" H="87" Pp="53" S="16" T="16" V="GO" W="10" U="4">720</Rep>
    <Rep D="NW" F="14" G="25" H="66" Pp="7" S="16" T="17" V="VG" W="3" U="3">900</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="22" H="67" Pp="1" S="13" T="16" V="VG" W="1" U="2">1080</Rep>
    <Rep D="WNW" F="12" G="16" H="79" Pp="1" S="9" T="14" V="VG" W="2" U="0">1260</Rep>
  </Period>
  <Period type="Day" value="2014-08-18Z">
    ...
  </Period>
</Location>
```

And below is how I want to read it, but I don't want to change the file itself:

```
<Location i="3808" lat="50.218" lon="-5.33" name="CAMBORNE" country="ENGLAND" continent="EUROPE" elevation="87.0">
  <Rep D="WSW" F="11" G="18" H="91" Pp="0" S="4" T="11" V="VG" W="1" U="1">360</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="15" G="11" H="73" Pp="1" S="9" T="16" V="VG" W="3" U="1">540</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="14" G="18" H="66" Pp="3" S="13" T="17" V="VG" W="3" U="4">720</Rep>
  <Rep D="W" F="15" G="18" H="67" Pp="5" S="13" T="17" V="VG" W="7" U="5">900</Rep>
  <Rep D="W" F="13" G="20" H="75" Pp="34" S="13" T="16" V="VG" W="7" U="1">1080</Rep>
  <Rep D="WSW" F="12" G="18" H="83" Pp="7" S="9" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">1260</Rep>
  <Rep D="W" F="12" G="20" H="83" Pp="38" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">0</Rep>
  <Rep D="W" F="12" G="18" H="85" Pp="8" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="7" U="0">180</Rep>
  <Rep D="W" F="12" G="20" H="86" Pp="53" S="11" T="14" V="VG" W="12" U="1">360</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="22" H="79" Pp="30" S="16" T="16" V="VG" W="7" U="1">540</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="25" H="87" Pp="53" S="16" T="16" V="GO" W="10" U="4">720</Rep>
  <Rep D="NW" F="14" G="25" H="66" Pp="7" S="16" T="17" V="VG" W="3" U="3">900</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="13" G="22" H="67" Pp="1" S="13" T="16" V="VG" W="1" U="2">1080</Rep>
  <Rep D="WNW" F="12" G="16" H="79" Pp="1" S="9" T="14" V="VG" W="2" U="0">1260</Rep>
  ...
</Location>
```

I don't want to go through all the periods and then go through all the reps inside each one, I just want to get all the reps at once. For example, I want to do:

```
foreach(rep in location)
```

Instead of:

```
foreach(period in location)
  foreach(rep in period)
```

Without editing the file. Also, if I did this how would I find out which period a rep came from? Thanks

Comment: _"if I did this how would I find out which period a rep came from?"_ - A nested `foreach()` would be ideal for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Linq to XML you can just select the `Rep` nodes like this, by using the [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var reps = xml.Descendants("Rep");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, loops trough the  nodes.

```
        var doc = new XDocument(XDocument.Load("XML.xml"));
        foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("Rep"))
        {
            // Do something with the node
        }
```

Comment: Great! Works as well, but is there a way I could tell which period the rep has come from as I loop through the reps? Is there an XPath property or something that shows me the nodes that specific rep is nested in? So I can get the date attribute from the period element. Thanks.

Comment: You could use item.Parent.Attribute("value").ToString(); to get the value

Comment: Perfect, thanks. LINQ to XML looks so much easier than using System.Xml